# terminal app on my iphone 5?

Tags: terminal, iphone

Which app do i use to get terminal on my iphone 5? 
I got something that i thought was terminal, but im not sure. I want to modify my iphone using terminal. 
I downloaded serverauditor already.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

#### Local

To use a local terminal, you have to jailbreak.
At which point you would install mobileterminal<sup>(with cydia)</sup> to access the local shell.

#### Remote

For accessing other systems, you would need a ssh client <sup>(although you could do the above, and run ssh)</sup>.
I recommend [prompt](https://panic.com/prompt/).

Also, if you jailbroke your iPhone and installed openssh, you could just use prompt to connect locally; it has a better interface than mobileterminal.